# Git - ignoring a single commit

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I had branch A that contained a lot of code and to facilitate merging it, I had to scrape off one big feature - that is, I created a commit deleting some of the new files I created. Thus creating branch B. B got merged to develop, and develop branch piled up some more changes.

Now I want to revisit branch A and merge develop into it. Scraping off was in a single commit. So I would like to

```
git fetch origin develop
```

and merge all commits but a certain commit (I merged all commits up to the deleting commit, but I also want to merge all the commits after that deleting commit [there are no expected conflicts]).

To sum up:

> B = A + (deleting commit)
>
> develop = B + commit1 + commit2 + ... + commit[n]

I want to create:

> A' = develop - deleting commit

Is there a way to create a negating commit and maybe stash that? Then I can `git pull origin develop & git stash pop`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you considered git revert?

Comment: Yes. That did the job. Thanks. git revert <commit>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you have branches `A`, `B`, and `develop` in your local git repository. In order to have `develop` contain all commits except the large-scale deleting commit, do the following:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase -i A
```

You will then get a screen that gives you a list of all your commits since the head of branch `A`. Delete the line with the commit you don't want, and then save the file (usually the interface is in `vi`, so entering `:wq` will save and quit. Check out `vi` documentation for more details). Once you've done that, the `develop` branch will now have all the commits except the big deletion. Don't worry, though, because `B` will still have the delete commit, and you can always go back to it by checking out branch `B` if you want.

Caveats: you may end up with some conflict or other as a result of doing these operations. Also, there is no guarantee that you code will actually work; git is a text tool, not a "code" tool per-se.